# Getting a JSON from XAMPP local server?

Tags: jquery, html, json, apache, xampp

I am trying to get an integer from a JSON file, to store into a 'var' and then use it in Google Charts for Y value.

I have an example:

**MY JSON FILE**

```
{
 "name": "ProjA",
 "sp": 10,
 "current": 20
}
```

And here is the fiddle to my **HTML FILE**: http://jsfiddle.net/86aBp/3/
(You cannot see the included sources here, but I do have them correctly included in my files)

I am running an XAMPP Apache Local Server. I have saved the JSON file into location HTDOCS (inside XAMPP Folder) as they said in tutorial. I have also saved the HTML file in there just in case.

But I still cannot get it to work. Can anyone please help me?
Is something wrong with the AJAX call?
Or is something wrong with variable storing?
Or maybe I dont understand good enough how XAMPP Local Servers work?

Thank you.
David

Comment: "But I still cannot get it to work"  What does this mean?  And is the missing " in your JSON a typo or the cause of your problems?

Comment: Is your AJAX call failing? What do you see in the console?

Comment: This are the errors fromt he console: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/test.json. Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4
Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined "

Comment: I am not saying that I'm in a right direction, but this is what I came up on my own.  So if anyon has other approach that would work - please post a fiddle.